# transform scale content and save width container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scaletransform

I try to produce the same effect of the browser zoom to a div in my page,
This div contains several thumbnails with a float left on each thumbnail,
My zoom works very well on chrome and opera exactly as I want, but on firefox and IE : if zoom out it makes white space and if zoom in it creates scrolls.
Can anyone help me please.

```js
$('#zoom-in').click(function() {
   updateZoom(0.1);
});

$('#zoom-out').click(function() {
   updateZoom(-0.1);
});


zoomLevel = 1;

var updateZoom = function(zoom) {
   zoomLevel += zoom;
   $('.zoom').css({ zoom: zoomLevel, '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')','-ms-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')', 'transform-origin': 'top left' });
}
```

```css
.panel{
 float:left;
 margin-right:20px;
 width:150px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="zoom-in">zoom in</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="zoom-out">zoom out</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row zoom" style="margin-top:20px;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum</div>
   </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum</div>
   </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum</div>
   </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum</div>
   </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum</div>
   </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum dolor sit amet lorum ipsum</div>
   </div>

     
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No one can help me :(